# Getting data-fields from td:first row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a table that gets created using php drawing straight out of a database. Each `td` is editable and, when the mouse is clicked elsewhere, the new data is sent to the database and updated dynamically through `.ajax()`. That all works flawless. It does so through the `data-fields` of each `td`. They correspond with the field name in the database so the query has the proper WHERE clause.

Now, I have an ADD button that creates a new row of data that is also editable and can be edited and saved in the same manner. Currently I can add a row. I am trying to create an array of the `data-fields` from the first row of `td` so I can then add those to the newly created `td` during their creation loop. I am only able to get the `data-field` of the first and/or second `td`, though, not the entire row as I am intending. How, given the code I have, can I do that? Is it even possible with the configuration that I have? Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    /* Add a new table row to the bottom of the table */  
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $(".add").click(function() {  
            $("#table").each(function() {  
                //create array  

                /* $('.edit_tr:last').find('.edit_td').each(function() {  
                    var fieldArray = [];  
                    fieldArray.push($('.edit_tr:last').find('.edit_td').attr('data-field'));
                }); */     

                var fieldArray = [];  
                // fieldArray.push($('.edit_tr:last').find('.edit_td').last().attr('data-field'));  

                var $table = $(this);  
                // var field = $('.edit_tr').find('td:last').attr('data-field');  

                var id=$('#table tr:last').attr('id');  
                var $tr = $("#table").children('tr');  
                // var $th = $(this).closest('table').find('th').eq($(this).index());  

                // Number of td's in the last table row  
                var n = $('tr:last td', this).length;  
                var tds = '<tr class="edit_tr" id="' + id++ + '">';  

                // array  
                currentDataField = $('.edit_tr:first').find('.edit_td').first().attr('data-field');  
                console.log(currentDataField);  

                for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {  
                    fieldArray.push(currentDataField);  

                    currentDataField = $('.edit_tr:first').find('.edit_td [data-field=' + currentDataField + ']').next().attr('data-field');  
                    // currentDataField = $('.edit_tr').find('.edit_td').nextAll().attr('data-field');  
                }

                console.log('fieldArray ' + fieldArray);  
                // console.log(field);  

                for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {  
                    tds += '<td class="edit_td"><input type="text" class="editbox" id="' +  
                    id + '" data-field="' + fieldArray[i] + '"/>&nbsp;</td>';  

                    console.log('fieldArray loop ' + fieldArray[i]);  
                }  
                tds += '</tr>';  

                // console.log(tds);  

                if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {  
                    $('tbody', this).append(tds);  
                }
                else {  
                    $(this).append(tds);  
                }  
            });  
        });  
    });  
</script>
```

PHP code for table creation:

```
public function displayTable($table)
{
    //connect to DB
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    echo "<table id='table' border='1'>";   //start an HTML table

    $dbtable = $table;
    $fields =array();
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$dbtable);

    //fill fields array with fields from table in database
    while ($x = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $fields[] = $x['Field'];
    }

    $fieldsnum = count($fields);    //number of fields in array

    //create table header from dbtable fields
    foreach ($fields as $f)
    {
        echo "<th>".$f."</th>";
    }

    //create table rows from dbtable rows
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM ".$dbtable);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $rowid = $row[$fields[0]];

        echo "<tr class='edit_tr' id='".$rowid."'>";
        foreach ($fields as $f) 
        { 
            echo "<td class='edit_td' data-field='".$f."'><span id='".$rowid."' class='text'>".$row[$f]."</span>
            <input type='text' value='".$row[$f]."' class='editbox' id='".$rowid."' data-field='".$f."'/> </td>"; 
        }
        $rowid++;

        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";    //close the HTML table

    $recordid = $rowid;

    //close connection
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample HTML?  It would make it easier to be able to see the code that you are trying to retrieve the values from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there's a lot of code in there (and I'm not a PHP user, so I had to give it my best shot at testing out on some sample HTML   :D   ), so here's what I think will get you past the issue that you are having with the `data-field` values, but I'll stop there:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        /* Add a new table row to the bottom of the table */  
        $(".add").click(function() {
            var fieldArray = [];

            var $table = $("#table");
            var $lastRow = $table.find("tr:last");
            var $dataFields = $lastRow.find("td");

            $dataFields.each(function() {
                fieldArray.push($(this).attr("data-field"));
            });

            . . . .
```

That should get you your `fieldArray` value, populated with the `data-field` values from all of the `td` elements in the last `row` of the `table`.

A couple of side notes:

- again, my PHP isn't great, but it doesn't look like you are creating your `th` values inside a row in the table . . . they really should be wrapped in a `tr` element
- you could get the `$dataFields` value in one line of code (several ways, actually), but splitting it up into three lines, like I did, is actually faster (and a little easier to read, in my opinion   :)   ).

Comment: Thanks! I have a new issue now, though. I cannot get the .edit_td click even to respond to the newly created row. I'll post that problem in another question if I can't figure it out soon. Again, thanks.

Comment: If you are using JQuery 1.7 or later, use `$("#table").on("click", ".edit_td", function() { . . .` instead of `$(".edit_td").click(function() { . . .`.  That should make any `edit_td` elements (current of future) inside `#table` respond to the click.  If you are using an earlier version of JQuery, look here for more information on other options (like the `live` method): http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I actually just used Ajax and allowed the dad button to add a new blank record into the database and on the reload it is editable.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you set data attributes via jQuery function `.data()`, then these attributes are hidden attributes and cannot be found from $('.item [data-...]').
2. if you need to set string or number to data attribute, then set it with `.attr('data-NAME', value)` function
3. You can find all elements without searching data attribute and then filter elements with function [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

Comment: They are not set via jQuery. I have modified my post to show how the table is created. I will look into `.map()` I saw it while researching my problem, but had trouble fully understanding it. I'll give it another try.